# Progressive-download video-streaming C++

Tags: c++, video-streaming, progressive-download

Can someone give me some hints on using http progressive download in non http applications. I need to stream some video frames to a client application and display them. I need to develop the server side application and the client side application. I presume that the server side isn't too hard( I just receive a request and start transferring ). The client side is the problem for me. How can I approach this problem with regards to:

- caching ( need some sort of caching in file )
- indexing( the user must be able to salt to a specific time )
- clean up( when to discard the file )

Shortly, I need an application in C++ that replicates the behavior of flash player.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What platform are you targetting?

Comment: Also, "non-http application" doesn't really make much sense, given that suitable socket and HTTP libraries are available for pretty much any combination of languages and platform you'd care to use.

Comment: "using http progressive download in non http applications" if you used that (http download), would that no make your application a http application?

Comment: Never mind! Good replies! I had an epiphany just reading your replies. Thanks.